# Existence of irreducible subvariety of rational curves in Fano with specific generic spilitting type

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective Fano variety of dimension $n$ with Picard number one over the field of complex numbers and different from the projective space.

Question: Does there exist an irreducible subvariety $K$ of rational curves in $X$ which cover $X$ such that for a general $l \in K, TX\vert_l = \oplus_{i-1}^n \mathcal{O}(a_i) \oplus \mathcal{O}$, where $a_i > 0$.